# Rails using has_many through associations

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2, has-many-through

this is a noob question- i have 3 associated tables i am trying to access.

The Patient model has:

```
has_many :charts
has_many :providers, :through => :charts
```

The Provider model has:

```
has_many :charts 
has_many :patients, :through => :charts
```

and the Chart model has:

```
belongs_to :patient
belongs_to :provider
```

i pull the current_user.id to setup the @provider which works fine.

```
@provider = Provider.where(:user_id => current_user.id).first
```

then i use that @provider.id to create a hash of charts i need which also works

```
@charts = Chart.where(:provider_id => @provider.id)
```

but then when i try to create a hash of the patients from the @charts hash it breaks....

```
@patients = Patient.where(:id => @charts.patient_id)
```

says 'undefined method `patient_id' for #'
[patient_id is one of the columns in the charts table]

What am i doing wrong? Help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
@patients = Patient.where(:id => @charts.map(&:patient_id))
```

The @charts collection doesn't automatically collect the patient_id's of it's members.  The other two queries work because you're acting on a single record, whereas in the last query, you're acting on the returned collection from the second query.

Answer (score 0):

I think to access a column you may need to do something like this:

```
@patients =  Patient.where(:id => @charts[:patient_id])
```